# Read file 'filename' into character buffer 'text'

Tags: c, bash, shell, command

I want to know how would I get this C code running from the command line in the Bash shell?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Size of character buffer to read in a file. */
#define BUFFSIZE 1000000

/* Read file 'filename' into character buffer 'text'.*/

long read_file(char *filename, char *text ) {
FILE *fp   = fopen(filename, "r");
   long  size = 0; // Number of characters read.
   len  = 0;

if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, 
            "Error could not open file: %s\n", 
            strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

/* Go to the end of the file. */
if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
    /* Get the size of the file. */
    size = ftell(fp);
    if (size == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, 
                "Error could not open file: %s\n",
                 strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    /* Go back to the start of the file. */
    if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, 
                "Error rewinding to start of file: %s\n",
                 strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    /* Read the entire file into memory. */
    len = fread(text, sizeof(char), (size_t)size, fp);
    if (len == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, 
                "Error reading file into memory: %s\n", 
                 strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    } else {
       text[++len] = '\0'; /* Add a null-terminator. */
    }
}
(void)fclose(fp);
return size;
}
```

So thats all the code in the file just not sure of the commands i use as i have already used: chmod +x filename to make it runnable then i have typed ./filename to run but just getting error messages so there is something wrong i am doing i just don't know what it is

Comment: "but just getting error messages" is useless unless you tell us what exactly those error messages are.

Comment: For a start, you need to have a `main()` function.

Comment: Did you compile the program? Or did you just type `chmod +x filename` on the source code file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concern yourself less about the size of the file and more about the sizeof of the buffer you are writing into (you might be wiping out data that is not part of the input `text`).  Besides fread will return the number of bytes read.

Consider this:

```
size_t read_file(char *filename, char *text, size_t len)
{
    size_t rc = -1;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp)
    {
        rc = fread(text, sizeof(char), len, fp);
        text[rc - 1] = '\0'; /* force null termination */
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error could not open %s: %s\n",
                filename, strerror(errno));
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Then an example call:

```
int main()
{
    size_t len;
    char buffer[1024];
    len = read_file("file.txt", buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    /* more code here */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you compiled your code? try `gcc <file.c> -o <outputName>`

Answer (score 0):

I only get a couple of error messages. First, `strerror` and `errno` require these headers:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Then `len` isn't declared with a type:

```
int len  = 0;
```

After that, you require main:

```
int main() {
   // do something
}
```